# Unexpected token 'END OF FILE' at position 0 (JSON)

Tags: java, json, parsing, token, eof

I'm trying to retreive a name from a UUID via a website, using the API Mojang provided.

This is the code I use (I verified that it works):

```
@Override
public Map<UUID, String> call() throws Exception {
    Map<UUID, String> uuidStringMap = new HashMap<UUID, String>();
    for (UUID uuid : uuids) {
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(
                PROFILE_URL + uuid.toString().replace("-", ""))
                .openConnection();

        JSONObject response;

        System.out.println("String: " + fromStream(connection.getInputStream()));
        System.out.print("Line: " + uuid.toString());

        String name = null;

        try {
            response = (JSONObject) jsonParser
                    .parse(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

            name = (String) response.get("name");
            if (name == null) {
                continue;
            }
            String cause = (String) response.get("cause");
            String errorMessage = (String) response.get("errorMessage");
            if (cause != null && cause.length() > 0) {
                throw new IllegalStateException(errorMessage);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.print("Could not parse uuid '" + uuid.toString() + "' to name!");
            System.out.print("Trying Bukkit.getOfflinePlayer()");

            OfflinePlayer oPlayer = Bukkit.getOfflinePlayer(uuid);

            if (oPlayer != null && oPlayer.getFirstPlayed() != 0) {
                name = oPlayer.getName();

                System.out.print("Got player " + name);
            } else {
                System.out.print("Could not retrieve player with Bukkit.getOfflinePlayer()");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //throw new Exception("Could not parse uuid '" + uuid.toString() + "' to name!");
        }


        uuidStringMap.put(uuid, name);
    }
    return uuidStringMap;
}
```

Don't mind all the System.out.print lines, that's just to debug things.

It errors with this error:

```
[17:35:56 WARN]: Unexpected token END OF FILE at position 0.
[17:35:56 WARN]:        at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(Unknown Source)
[17:35:56 WARN]:        at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(Unknown Source)
[17:35:56 WARN]:        at me.armar.plugins.autorank.util.uuid.NameFetcher.call(
NameFetcher.java:59)
[17:35:56 WARN]:        at me.armar.plugins.autorank.util.uuid.UUIDManager$2.run
(UUIDManager.java:222)
[17:35:56 WARN]:        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Now, I've run the returned json through a few JSON online parsers. They all tell me the JSON is correct. This is the JSON that is being returned:

```
{"id":"cb994e15a57a4157953ab29577229ebe","name":"tator0 1","properties":[{"name":"textures","value":"eyJ0aW1lc3RhbXAiOjE0MDQ4MzM3NTM0MTYsInByb2ZpbGVJZCI6ImNiOTk0ZTE1YTU3YTQxNTc5NTNhYjI5NTc3MjI5ZWJlIiwicHJvZmlsZU5hbWUiOiJ0YXRvcjAxIiwiaXNQdWJsaWMiOnRydWUsInRleHR1cmVzIjp7IlNLSU4iOnsidXJsIjoiaHR0cDovL3RleHR1cmVzLm1pbmVjcmFmdC5uZXQvdGV4dHVyZS80Nzk5MjQ4NGJmNjUyODJhMTQzOWI0MGQ1NWU2ZTRjZGQxNGRmYzAyNGE0MzA3Y2M2YTM1M2Q4MzY1OThkZDUifX19","signature":"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"}],"legacy":true}
```

I saw that there also was someone else with a kind of similiar issue, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19945832/punexpected-token-end-of-file-at-position-0-p).

**Where could that unexpected token be?**

Answer (score 3):

Try applying .toString() to your input string before parsing.

For example:

```
DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
String dataIn = in.readUTF();
JSONObject jobj = (JSONObject) parser.parse(dataIn.toString());
```

Worked for me just moments ago. :D

Comment: Didn't worked for me :(
And any idea of why turn String into String would help?

Comment: I haven't looked at the implementation details, so I cannot give a definitive answer. However, my guess is that it may have something to do with how DataInputStream includes an "END OF FILE" character through readUTF(). Perhaps the String.toString() method strips the "END OF FILE" character?

But if it didn't work for you, then my hypothesis is probably mistaken.

Comment: If above doesn't work then we can try ===>
String dataIn = new JsonParser().parse("{ - json string with whitespaces - }").toString().trim();

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was trying to parse empty file. So, I just added simple check before parsing and issue had disappeared.

Comment: ,can you add an example.